# Alternative layout is applied to an article but not the other

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3.x and create an article override. It works fine for some articles. But when I apply to another article, inside a single article menu item, it not work.

**UPDATE**

Here is my entire override file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');

// Create shortcuts to some parameters.
$params  = $this->item->params;
$images  = json_decode($this->item->images);
$urls    = json_decode($this->item->urls);
$canEdit = $params->get('access-edit');
$user    = JFactory::getUser();
$info    = $params->get('info_block_position', 0);
JHtml::_('behavior.caption');

?>
<div class="item-page<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx?>">
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading') && $params->get('show_title')) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
    </div>
    <?php endif;
if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && !$this->item->paginationposition && $this->item->paginationrelative)
{
    echo $this->item->pagination;
}
?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_title') || $params->get('show_author')) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>
            <?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
                <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED'); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && !empty($this->item->readmore_link)) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>"> <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>
        <p class="date-created"><?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (!$this->print) : ?>
        <?php if ($canEdit || $params->get('show_print_icon') || $params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <span class="icon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span> </a>
            <?php // Note the actions class is deprecated. Use dropdown-menu instead. ?>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu actions">
                <?php if ($params->get('show_print_icon')) : ?>
                <li class="print-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_popup', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
                <li class="email-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.email', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
                <li class="edit-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="pull-right">
        <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_screen', $this->item, $params); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $useDefList = ($params->get('show_modify_date') || $params->get('show_publish_date') || $params->get('show_create_date')
    || $params->get('show_hits') || $params->get('show_category') || $params->get('show_parent_category') || $params->get('show_author')); ?>
    <?php if ($useDefList && ($info == 0 || $info == 2)) : ?>
        <div class="article-info muted">
            <dl class="article-info">
            <!--<dt class="article-info-term"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_INFO'); ?></dt>-->

            <?php if ($params->get('show_author') && !empty($this->item->author )) : ?>
                <dd class="createdby">
                    <?php $author = $this->item->created_by_alias ? $this->item->created_by_alias : $this->item->author; ?>
                    <?php if (!empty($this->item->contactid) && $params->get('link_author') == true) : ?>
                        <?php
                        $needle = 'index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=' . $this->item->contactid;
                        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
                        $item = $menu->getItems('link', $needle, true);
                        $cntlink = !empty($item) ? $needle . '&Itemid=' . $item->id : $needle;
                        ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', JHtml::_('link', JRoute::_($cntlink), $author)); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', $author); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_parent_category') && !empty($this->item->parent_slug)) : ?>
                <dd class="parent-category-name">
                    <?php $title = $this->escape($this->item->parent_title);
                    $url = '<a href="'.JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->parent_slug)).'">'.$title.'</a>';?>
                    <?php if ($params->get('link_parent_category') && !empty($this->item->parent_slug)) : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $url); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $title); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_category')) : ?>
                <dd class="category-name">
                    <?php $title = $this->escape($this->item->category_title);
                    $url = '<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->catslug)) . '">' . $title . '</a>';?>
                    <?php if ($params->get('link_category') && $this->item->catslug) : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $url); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $title); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_publish_date')) : ?>
                <dd class="published">
                    <!--<span class="icon-calendar"></span>--> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->publish_up, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($info == 0) : ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_modify_date')) : ?>
                    <dd class="modified">
                        <!--<span class="icon-calendar"></span>--> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_LAST_UPDATED', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
                    <dd class="create">
                        <!--<span class="icon-calendar"></span>--> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($params->get('show_hits')) : ?>
                    <dd class="hits">
                        <span class="icon-eye-open"></span> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_HITS', $this->item->hits); ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </dl>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (!$params->get('show_intro')) : echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayTitle; endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>

    <?php if (isset($urls) && ((!empty($urls->urls_position) && ($urls->urls_position == '0')) || ($params->get('urls_position') == '0' && empty($urls->urls_position)))
        || (empty($urls->urls_position) && (!$params->get('urls_position')))) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('links'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('access-view')):?>
    <?php if (isset($images->image_fulltext) && !empty($images->image_fulltext)) : ?>
    <?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_fulltext)) ? $params->get('float_fulltext') : $images->float_fulltext; ?>
    <div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
    <?php if ($images->image_fulltext_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_caption) . '"';
    endif; ?>
    src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_alt); ?>"/> </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && !$this->item->paginationposition && !$this->item->paginationrelative):
        echo $this->item->pagination;
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php if (isset ($this->item->toc)) :
        echo $this->item->toc;
    endif; ?>
    <div class="article-text"><?php echo $this->item->text; ?></div>

    <?php if ($useDefList && ($info == 1 || $info == 2)) : ?>
        <div class="article-info muted">
            <dl class="article-info">
            <!--<dt class="article-info-term"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_INFO'); ?></dt>-->

            <?php if ($info == 1) : ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_author') && !empty($this->item->author )) : ?>
                    <dd class="createdby">
                        <?php $author = $this->item->created_by_alias ? $this->item->created_by_alias : $this->item->author; ?>
                        <?php if (!empty($this->item->contactid) && $params->get('link_author') == true) : ?>
                        <?php
                        $needle = 'index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=' . $this->item->contactid;
                        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
                        $item = $menu->getItems('link', $needle, true);
                        $cntlink = !empty($item) ? $needle . '&Itemid=' . $item->id : $needle;
                        ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', JHtml::_('link', JRoute::_($cntlink), $author)); ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_WRITTEN_BY', $author); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_parent_category') && !empty($this->item->parent_slug)) : ?>
                    <dd class="parent-category-name">
                        <?php   $title = $this->escape($this->item->parent_title);
                        $url = '<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->parent_slug)) . '">' . $title . '</a>';?>
                        <?php if ($params->get('link_parent_category') && $this->item->parent_slug) : ?>
                            <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $url); ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PARENT', $title); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_category')) : ?>
                    <dd class="category-name">
                        <?php   $title = $this->escape($this->item->category_title);
                        $url = '<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->catslug)) . '">' . $title . '</a>';?>
                        <?php if ($params->get('link_category') && $this->item->catslug) : ?>
                            <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $url); ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY', $title); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($params->get('show_publish_date')) : ?>
                    <dd class="published">
                        <!--<!--<span class="icon-calendar"></span>-->-->
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->publish_up, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($params->get('show_create_date')) : ?>
                <dd class="create">
                    <!--<!--<span class="icon-calendar"></span>-->-->
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_modify_date')) : ?>
                <dd class="modified">
                    <!--<span class="icon-calendar"></span>-->
                    <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_LAST_UPDATED', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('show_hits')) : ?>
                <dd class="hits">
                    <span class="icon-eye-open"></span> <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_HITS', $this->item->hits); ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </dl>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && $this->item->paginationposition && !$this->item->paginationrelative):
    echo $this->item->pagination;
?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (isset($urls) && ((!empty($urls->urls_position) && ($urls->urls_position == '1')) || ($params->get('urls_position') == '1'))) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('links'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php //optional teaser intro text for guests ?>
    <?php elseif ($params->get('show_noauth') == true && $user->get('guest')) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
    <?php //Optional link to let them register to see the whole article. ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('show_readmore') && $this->item->fulltext != null) :
        $link1 = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
        $link = new JURI($link1);?>
    <p class="readmore">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
        <?php $attribs = json_decode($this->item->attribs); ?>
        <?php
        if ($attribs->alternative_readmore == null) :
            echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
        elseif ($readmore = $this->item->alternative_readmore) :
            echo $readmore;
            if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
                echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
            endif;
        elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
            echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE_TITLE');
        else :
            echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE');
            echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
        endif; ?>
        </a>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
if (!empty($this->item->pagination) && $this->item->pagination && $this->item->paginationposition && $this->item->paginationrelative) :
    echo $this->item->pagination;
?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayContent; ?> </div>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I discovered one thing: if the article is associated with a menu item (type:Category List), the Alternative Layout works. But when the article is associated a menu item (type:Single Article), the Alternative Layout does not work. How do the Alternative Layout function in both cases?

Comment: code? link? example? what have you tried?

Comment: I save a copy of default.php (com_content/views/article/tmpl) in my html template folder and apply alternative layout to some articles using a normal procedure. But it working only for articles inside a specific category. I try to apply it in article inside another category but nothing happens.

Comment: please show the code you are using.

Comment: There are two kinds of alternates, the kind with an xml file and the kind without. The kind without applies to actual items, but it can be overridden by a menu becuase menu is more specific than item.  THe kind with an xml file only can be used via menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

I Create a custom menu item type.

More informations here: http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_2.5

And here: http://jure-stern.si/blog/custom-menu-item-types-in-joomla-with-xml-files/